# Restlet - Jax-RS 2.0 aware?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, restlet

I saw that Restlet already has a stable 2.0 Version and even further testing and unstable 2.1 and 2.2 version. Are they already JAX-RS 2.0 aware? If its true, they seem to be further in the JAX-RS implementation than the jersey jax-rs reference framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restlet Framework (RF) versions are not synced at all with JAX-RS versions. Currently RF 2.1 only supports JAX-RS 1.0.

Note however that we have added (non standard) JAX-RS client-side support in RF 2.1 via the org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.JaxRsClientResource class.

We are looking forward to support standard JAX-RS API 2.0 version when it is stable, probably in RF 3.0.