# @JeromeLouvel When will Restlet framework support JAX-RS 2.0 API？

Tags: jax-rs, restlet

I'm eagerly hoping that the [RestletFramework](http://restlet.com/) can be aware of JAX-RS 2.0 standard API, either by natively supporting or by adding somewhat extension.

In [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382273/restlet-jax-rs-2-0-aware) posted two years ago I saw the author of Restlet said that Restlet would make its step to JAX-RS 2.0 when it is stable, but we can't see any progress in terms of JAX-RS 2.0.

Whereas some other REST framework such as Jersey or ApacheCXF have announced its support for JSR-339, I want to know when the Restlet will??